# Microsoft Graph API C# Create Event

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api

I am using the C# SDK to create calendar events to book locations. Some of these locations have a BookInPolicy in place, preventing my user from creating bookings against them and they are automatically declined.
Is there any way to see within the Graph API that the location has declined the event? I have added the location as an attendee of type Resource but the response for the attendee does not come back with a declined status.
I also don't seem to be able to see this data when checking the availability for the location.
When there is no BookInPolicy or the designated user is included in the BookInPolicy, everything works as expected.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 0):

> > I have added the location as an attendee of type Resource but the response for the attendee does not come back with a declined status

You should be getting a declined unless they have a delegate policy in place in that case the meeting would be waiting on the acceptance of the delegate it could be related to a miss configuration https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/calendars/resource-doesnt-respond-to-meeting-requests-when-using-booking.

The policy is held in the Mailbox in a FAI (folder associated Item) which the Graph doesn't allow you access to and there is currently no other endpoint that allows that type of access. In the places API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/room?view=graph-rest-1.0 there is bookingType but AFAIK it only works for a limited subset of policy settings.